# Stop a wordpress submit if not valid. (WPCasa)

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm using the WPCasa Dashboard Plugin to allow a user to submit a real estate object. I have to use an external service to validate the object. I want to block WP updating the database if the response from the service has an error.

I'm using wpcasa's own hook for my function.

---

This is the part of the `functions.php` in my child theme:

```
function newListingAdded($ID, $post ) {

  ...

  if ($post->post_date === $post->post_modified) {
    // new post
    $response = wp_remote_post( $targetUrl.'listings/new', $options );
  } else {
    $response = wp_remote_post( $targetUrl.'listings/update', $options );
  }

  $output = json_decode($response['body']);
  if (is_array($output)) {
    $_SESSION['messages'] = [];
    foreach ($output as $error) {
      if (isset($error->msg)) {
        array_push($_SESSION['messages'], ['danger', $error->msg]);
      }
    } 
  }
}
add_action( 'publish_listing', 'newListingAdded', 10, 2 );
```

so far everything works like intended. I just can't figure out how to stop wordpress from actually submitting the data.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using the `publish_listing` action from WPCasa (I couldn't find it in the WPCasa documentation, though), you can instead use the official `wp_insert_post_data` filter from WordPress.

Now, WP doesn't officially support a way to prevent a post from being saved by using an action/hook, however, if you look at the WP source code (reference: https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.7/src/wp-includes/post.php#L3281) you'll see that WP takes the `$data` value (an associative array of field/value pairs to be saved to the database) returned from the `wp_insert_post_data` and passes it to $wpdb->update().

If you use the `wp_insert_post_data` and return a boolean false value instead of the actual `$data` parameter being received by the filter then it will prevent the post from being updated, as $wpdb->update() checks if $data is a valid array and not false, otherwise it doesn't do anything on the database (reference: https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.7/src/wp-includes/wp-db.php#L2023)

So, you can try using this code:

```
function newListingAdded($data, $postarr) {
  if (!$data['ID']) { // If no post ID is set then it's a new post
    $response = wp_remote_post( $targetUrl.'listings/new', $options );
  } else {
    $response = wp_remote_post( $targetUrl.'listings/update', $options );
  }

  $output = json_decode($response['body']);

  if (is_array($output)) {
    $_SESSION['messages'] = [];

    foreach ($output as $error) {
      if (isset($error->msg)) {
        $_SESSION['messages'][] = ['danger', $error->msg]; // You can use the [] shorthand operator instead of the more verbose array_push()
        $data = false; // If an error is found make $data false
      }
    } 
  }

  return $data;
}

add_filter( 'wp_insert_post_data', 'newListingAdded', 10, 2);
```

Here's the reference for this filter:
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_insert_post_data/